# TMUX does not print full prompt on the windows terminal

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux, prompt

Hello I have the following config for TMUX:

```shell
set -sg escape-time 50 # https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5931
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:RGB"
set -g mouse on

bind -n M-H previous-window
bind -n M-L next-window

# set prefix
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix


# Start indexing from 1
set -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1
# Ensure window index numbers get reordered on delete.
set-option -g renumber-windows on


set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
set -g @plugin 'catppuccin/tmux'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-yank'

# set vi-mode
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-v send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel


run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

But windows terminal does not render the prompt correctly. I have the following result:

[image]

You can see some characters are rendered incorrectly, and the colors are not well.

Could you suggest to me what I should check for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the font used can't display *glyphs*. A special font with extended characters is required to display the special characters that are used in your status bar on the right.

You're using the plugin **catppuccin/tmux**. In the [readme](https://github.com/catppuccin/tmux#readme) you can find the following paragraph:

> In order to have the correct icons displayed please use your favorite nerd fonts patched font.

Please make sure to install and configure a [Nerd font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/custom-prompt-setup#install-a-nerd-font) for your Windows Terminal.

As an alternative, you can avoid the usage of special characters by configuring alternative ones. You can try to add these options to your tmux config:

```bash
set -g @catppuccin_datetime_icon "A"
set -g @catppuccin_user_icon "B"
set -g @catppuccin_directory_icon "C"
set -g @catppuccin_window_icon "D"
set -g @catppuccin_session_icon "E"
set -g @catppuccin_host_icon "F"
```

Comment: That was the issue indeed. Thank you so much for your help